# Xcode 11.5 (11E608c) - Swift 5.2.4 illegal instruction: 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having a problem archiving my Swift code via Xcode.  I keep getting "Error. Illegal Instruction: 4"

Edit: Quick clarification - it builds and runs fine in debug for my device.  It will not build for release (archive)

My first error was in one of my dependencies I built via Carthage.  Tried to update all dependencies via carthage and they're all doing the same thing - "Error. Illegal Instruction: 4"

Here's the error from one on my dependencies I manually build and add in:

```
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
0  swift                    0x00000001133084ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000113307cc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7299e5fd _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2372278816
4  swift                    0x000000010f0507d7 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 9799
5  swift                    0x000000010efd1b73 main + 1283
6  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff727a5cc9 start + 1
error: Illegal instruction: 4 (in target 'libsignal-protocol-swift iOS' from project 'libsignal-protocol-swift')
```

Here's another one from a different dependency built via carthage:

```
139 1.      Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
140 0  swift                    0x00000001070674ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
141 1  swift                    0x0000000107066cc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
142 2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7299e5fd _sigtramp + 29
143 3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2372278816
144 4  swift                    0x0000000102daf7d7 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void    *, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 9799
145 5  swift                    0x0000000102d30b73 main + 1283
146 6  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff727a5cc9 start + 1
147 error: Illegal instruction: 4 (in target 'DynamicButton' from project 'DynamicButtonExample')
```

Here's it again from xcode trying to build my code:

```
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
0  swift                    0x000000010aeaf4ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010aeaecc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7299e5fd _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2372278816
4  swift                    0x0000000106bf77d7 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 9799
5  swift                    0x0000000106b78b73 main + 1283
6  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff727a5cc9 start + 1
error: Illegal instruction: 4 (in target 'Assistant' from project 'CareApp')
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on.  I've restarted, cleared DerivedData, cleaned Build Folder, etc.

All the errors are exactly the same whether built via xcode or command line (carthage builds via command line)

I think it's an issue w/ Swift 5.2.4? The last time I successfully archived was 5/26/20.  I'm now running Swift 5.2.4 and according to my computer it was created on 5/27/20.

Edit: I have also tried changing the optimization settings for release to "None" - same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling / enabling a whole module optimization or set a Custom Build Setting SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE to NO

Comment: Where is this setting? The only whole//incremental I see is under "compilation mode"

Edit: Which also had no effect - still fails

Comment: I suspect this is not going to fix things because carthage was building w/ -O whole-module-optimization and my xcode is not.  Neither one is working.

Comment: Do it for your Carthage builds

Comment: How do I disable whole module optimization for Carthage?

Comment: checkout your dependencies and then modify build settings for each project at the end execute Carthage build

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.  Right now I run carthage update --platform iOS

How should I change that command to do what you're suggesting?

Comment: Also - SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE -> NO was already set previously.

Comment: To update a project settings for a Carthage framework you have to go to a Carthage/Checkouts folder
then open a *.xcworkspace or *xcodeproj file and update a build settings. At the end execute carthage build --platform iOS